# What exactly does this log10(int) method in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, logarithm

I'm checking a Java code from an online test and I try to understand what exactly is this `log10()` method.

This is an image with the code from the test:

[image]
[image]

I added the code in my Eclipse and I get some errors:

```
public class Demo {

    public static String numbers(int from, int to) {

        int maxDigits = ceil(log10(to));
        int len = (to - from + 1) * (maxDigits + 1);
        char[] chars = new char[len];
        len = 0;

        for (int index = from; index < to; index++) {
            char[] reversed = new char[maxDigits];
            int wip = index;
            int digit = 0;

            while (wip > 0) {
                reversed[digit++] = (char) ('0' + wip % 10);
                wip = 10;
            }

            while (digit-- > 0) {
                chars[len++] = reversed[digit];
            }
            chars[len++] = ' ';
        }
        return new String(chars, len);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo.numbers(11, 15);
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me to understand what does this `ceil(log10(to))` statement? Because I get a compilation error at this line: "The method log10(int) is undefined for the type Demo". Anyway I think this code has some error because also I have another compilation error at the end "The constructor String(char[], int) is undefined".

I've did a Java test online and I have no idea what is the output. And now I want to check it to learn from it. Any feedback will be apreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Those are method calls which are not defined in your code snippet therefore we can not answer your question.

Comment: Maybe `Math.log10(int)`?

Comment: log10 is often used to get the numbers of digits of a number (decimal ofcourse)

Comment: @MuratKaragöz I completely agree with you. Having said that though, if this method does not compute the logarithm base 10 of the `int`, I would really be disappointed in the code's readability.

Comment: Also the last statement should probably be `new String(chars, 0, len);` for it to compile

Comment: You made a typo: `wip = 10;` needs to be `wip /= 10;` like in your image.

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10(double)

> Returns the base 10 logarithm of a double value.

Google search was "java math log10" and I then picked the first official API documentation, which was the third result.

Answer (score 1):

The code is simply missing imports.

```
import static java.lang.Math.log10;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(log10(100));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2.0
```

log10 is just the logarithm with base 10, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_logarithm).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your header, please consider these examples.

- log<sub>10</sub> 11 = 1.04139269
- log<sub>10</sub> 101 = 2.00432137
- log<sub>10</sub> 1001 = 3.00043408
- log<sub>10</sub> 10001 = 4.00004343
- log<sub>10</sub> 99999 = 4.99999566

log<sub>10</sub> tells you how many digits (in base 10) the number has (minus 1). So all the five digit numbers, from 10000 to 99999, have a log<sub>10</sub> that is greater than or equal to 4.0 but less than 5.0. If you take the ceil of the log<sub>10</sub>, you'll get 5.

Put another way, if x is any 5-digit number, then int(ceil(log<sub>10</sub> x)) = 5.